# Make div background 100% as much as window width

Tags: html, css

I have div content-3 which is inside container. I want to make this background color 100% for his height which may increase. I think this possible using css. Here is image of my requirement. [image]

```css
*{padding:0; margin:0; box-sizzing:border-box;}
.container{margin: 0px auto; width: 80%; border: 1px solid #333;}
.content{min-height:50px}
.content-3{background:green}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="content content-1">content 1</div>
<div class="content content-2">content 2</div>
<div class="content content-3">content 3</div>
<div class="content content-4">content 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet already matches your requirement.  What do you actually need then?

Comment: I want to make background color as much window width. now it's taking background color as per container width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative answer you could use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to achieve the same effect.

No changes to the HTML.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.content.content-3 {
    position: relative;
}
.content.content-3:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -10vw;
    right: 100%;
    background: green;
}
.content.content-3:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    right: -10vw;
    background: green;
}
```

Edit: Changed `-100%` to `-10vw` for left/right positions. `vw` means viewport width so given your container is `80%` wide, you want each side to extend `10vw` to make the full 100% with no horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

As a visual trick, you can add extra padding to the div and counteract using negative margins. However you have to add overflow-x:hidden to body to prevent horizontal scroll:

```css
*{padding:0; margin:0; box-sizzing:border-box;}
.container{margin: 0px auto; width: 80%; border: 1px solid #333;}
.content{min-height:50px}
.content-3{
  background:green;
  padding-left:100%;
  padding-right:100%;
  margin-left:-100%;
  margin-right:-100%;
}

body{overflow-x:hidden}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="content content-1">content 1</div>
<div class="content content-2">content 2</div> 
<div class="content content-3">content 3</div>
<div class="content content-4">content 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great....it's working....thanks...but why you used body{overflow-x:hidden} is there any other alternate for it?

Comment: margin:100% may overflow the window and cause horizontal scroll.

Comment: As with my pseudo-element answer below you could try using padding-left/padding-right = 10vw and margin-left/margin-right = -10vw

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to create multiple container elements you could do something like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content content-1">content 1</div>
    <div class="content content-2">content 2</div> 
</div>
<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content content-3">content 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content content-4">content 4</div>
</div>
```

Then just make container-wrapper full-width with a green background.

Comment: yes it will work...but i want all content div in one container. Thanks